# kde.points SpatialPixelsDataFrame to geojson

Tags: r, geojson, kernel-density

I have a multiple projected spatialpixelsdataframes produced from kde.points() and would like to use it in a leaflet map.
Basically the same as Brunsdon example with the New Haven crime data, except for Denver, CO.

I tried using writeOGR(), and geojson_write(), but both give me the error "Can't convert columns of class: array; column names: kde".

Also tried the From SpatialPixelsDataFrame method from the geojson_write example, but it give an error.

pixelsdf <- suppressWarnings(
    SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = burg.2015[c("Var1", "Var2")], data = burg.2015))
Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected

[image: About Burg.2015 data]
Is there a way to export it as is, or would I have to convert the spdf to a different object?

Answer (score 1):

The kde values from MASS::kde2d are stored as a matrix. The array coercion is to create a vector with the correct length. However, you cannot export an sp DataFrame object with an array in the @data slot and for some reason the function is not outputting a vector column. You can simply coerce the offending column into a vector using as.vector and overwriting it.

```
burg.2015@data$kde <- as.vector( burg.2015@data$kde )
```

However, here is a function that should suit your purposes. The output is a raster class object rather than a SpatialPixelsDataFrame. I also added an option to standardize the results to 0-1. The functions resulting object is a list but you are after the x$kde raster class object. The other element in the list is $bandwidth indicating the kernel bandwidth that was used. You can use writeRaster to output just about any raster format you would like to disk.

```
# 2D KDE function
#' @param x               SpatialPoints of SpatialPointsDataFrame object
#' @param bw              Bandwidth of Gaussian Kernel
#' @param n               Number of rows and columns (evaluation points)
#' @param ext             Extent of raster, coordinates as: c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#' @param standardize     Row standardize results to 0-1 (FALSE/TRUE)
#'
#' @return A list object with:
#' @return   kde        Raster class object of kernel density estimate
#' @return   bandwidth  Bandwidth of kernel
kde2D <- function (x, bw = NULL, n = 120, ext = NULL, 
                   standardize = FALSE) {
  if (is.null(bw)) { 
    bw <- c(MASS::bandwidth.nrd(coordinates(x)[,1]), 
            MASS::bandwidth.nrd(coordinates(x)[,2]))
  }     
  if (is.null(ext)) {
    ext <- c(range(coordinates(x)[,1]), 
             range(coordinates(x)[,2]))
  } else {
    ext <- c(sp::bbox(x)[1],sp::bbox(x)[3],sp::bbox(x)[2],sp::bbox(x)[4]) 
  }  
    kden <- MASS::kde2d(sp::coordinates(x)[,1], sp::coordinates(x)[,2], h = bw, 
                      n = n, lims = ext)

    if( standardize == TRUE ) {
      kden$z <- (kden$z - min(kden$z)) / (max(kden$z) - min(kden$z))  
    }                 
    kde.est <- sp::SpatialPoints(expand.grid(kden$x, kden$y))
    kde.est <- raster::raster(sp::SpatialPixelsDataFrame(kde.est, 
                              data.frame(kde = as.vector(array(kden$z, 
                              length(kden$z))))))                           
       sp::proj4string(kde.est) <- sp::proj4string(x)  
  return( list( kde=kde.est, bandwidth=bw) )
}

# Example
library(sp)
library(raster)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y

meuse.kde <- kde2D(meuse, bw = 1000, n = 500, standardize = TRUE)  
plot(meuse.kde$kde)
  plot(meuse, pch=20, cex=0.75, col="red", add=TRUE)
```